# tsparticles : Interruption in particle motion (defect in movement or has stutter and lag) after build in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, particles

everything works fine in development mode when I use `npm run start`, but in production and deployed mode after build (`npm run build`) there is Interruption in particle motion or it's way slow.

I changed and tested all the tsparticles options but it still did not work properly.

my react version is 17.0.2 , typescript 4.5.4 and tsParticles 1.38.0

```
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
export const Header = (props:any) => {

return (
<div>
<Particles
      id="tsparticles"
      options={ 
        {
          "background": {
            "color": {
              "value": "#00000095"
            },
            "position": "50% 50%",
            "repeat": "no-repeat",
            "size": "cover",
            "opacity": 1,
            "image": "url('/img/bg1.jpg')"
          },

         "backgroundMask": {
           "composite": "destination-out",
           "cover": {
             "color": {
               "value": {
                 "r": 255,
                 "g": 255,
                 "b": 255
               }
             },
             "opacity": 1
           },
           "enable": true
         },

         "fullScreen": {
           "enable": false,
           "zIndex": -10
         },
         "interactivity": {
           "events": {
             "onClick": {
               "enable": true,
               "mode": "push"
             },
             "onHover": {
               "enable": true,
               "mode": "bubble",
               "parallax": {
                 "force": 60
               }
             }
           }
         },
         "particles": {
           "color": {
             "value": "#ffffff"
           },
           "move": {
             "attract": {
               "rotate": {
                 "x": 600,
                 "y": 1200
               }
             },
             "enable": true,
             "outModes": {
               "bottom": "out",
               "left": "out",
               "right": "out",
               "top": "out",
               "default": "none"
             },
             "direction": "right",
             "speed": 2
           },
           "number": {
             "density": {
               "enable": true,
             },
             "value": 60
           },
           "opacity": {
             "value": {
               "min": 0.1,
               "max": 0.5
             },
             "animation": {
               "enable": true,
               "speed": 1,
               "minimumValue": 0.1
             }
           },
           "shape": {
             "options": {
               "polygon": {
                 "sides": 5
               },
               "star": {
                 "sides": 5
               }
             },
             "type": "square"
           },

           "size": {
             "random": {
               "enable": true,
               "minimumValue": 0,
             },
             "value": {
               "min": 5,
               "max": 20
             },
             "animation": {
               "speed": 10,
               "minimumValue": 0.1
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }

   }
  />
  </div>
  )
  }
```

I also changed the values of the `retina_detect` and `detectRetina` to false but it was not resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason for this issue, there is a problem with the **build tool or bundle file** that occurs when using the `npm run build` command.

now I am building the project with **`Webpack`** and there is no interruption but not full fixed.

also may be solved by changing the `browserslist` in `package.json`

Following for more details this issue:
https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/issues/2809