# tsParticles has worse performance on live-server

Tags: reactjs, particles, particles.js, react-particles-js

I am currently stuck and unable to locate the error. After building my react application containing the react-tsParticles package, I noticed a immense worse performance after publishing it on my nginx-based webserver. While in local development performance is fine, but the performance when visiting the live page is bad and not comparable to other examples on the internet.

I am not interested in advertising my page, but this is the [link](https://michaelholley.de/Skills) to it.
The Code can be found [here](https://github.com/MichaelHolley/michaelholley.de) on Github.

Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: The version `1.39.3` (released today) should fix this issue, try upgrading to it

Comment: Have you used mui in your project ?

Comment: No - I wanted to try out Tailwind CSS, so I went with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too

there is a problem with the **build tool** or bundle file that occurs when using the `npm run build` command.

also may be solved by changing the `browserslist` in `package.json`.

you can refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70625114/8730051

Comment: I can't say if it is THE fix, but in my opinion the performance got better. Your advice is much appreciated. Thanks :)
The Lighthouse Report-Feature is also showing better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this in 2024 and you are using react-vite project, using browserlist etc. won't help much I tried everything. what worked for me is to change vite.config file and using chunking stragery it impacts how node_modules are bundled and served.

```
 build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return "vendor";
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
```